# auto space between divs

Tags: css, html

I have to create a web page with a big div (grey colored) and many divs (black colored) near it (float left).

[image]

At the moment I'm using a margin (`margin-right`) which divides the black divs.
(I don't mind about the grey div because it's done.)
My problem is that the most right div for each row must not have the `margin-right` because i haven't got any more space to give it.
I can't create a specific class (`margin-right: 0`) for them because all the black divs will be added dynamically.
Is there any solution to my problem?

Comment: Give them a left margin instead and give the container the same amount of negative left margin.

Comment: @Juhana: there is no such thing as a negative *padding*!

Comment: all the divs have same class? @Rapstyle

Comment: @Juhana Are you referring to negative margin?

Comment: @Juhana, if he uses a left-margin he'll have the same problem, but on the other side.

Comment: @Richard That's where the negative margin comes in.

Comment: But if you're adding the div's dynamically can you not keep track of how many you've added and apply appropriate styling?

Comment: Were it not for the gray box you could use the [nth-child selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp).

Comment: Of course, but your answer only works for a fixed number of children, @AspiringAqib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/aFkfm/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="big"></div>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  ....
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#wrapper {
    margin-left: -20px;
}
div#big {
    float: left;
    width:  220px;
    height: 220px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
span {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}​
```

Comment: many thanks, i appreciated your solution so i decided to use it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd set the same margin on all the boxes (say `margin: 5px`) and then simply `margin: -5px` on the container: http://jsfiddle.net/ZKJeN/

```
body {
    background: #f3f3f3;
    padding: 15px;
}

/* Container */
ul {
    width: 300px;
    overflow: hidden; /* Clearfix */
    margin: -5px; /* To compensate for the 5px margin around each box */
    list-style: none;
}

    /* Small */
    ul li {
        background: #fff;

        float: left;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        margin: 5px;

        border: 5px solid #000;
    }

    /* Big */
    ul li:first-child {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
    }
```

Comment: Using `margin-right` might prevent small squares touching the right edge of the page or might force horizontal scrollbars (if page is designed so). On the other hand, it's nicely symmetric :)

Answer (score -1):

You can style them using the [nth-child selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp). It has a special form `(an+b)` where `a` is the cycle size and `b` is an offset.

```
.blackboxes:nth-child(3n+0) {margin-right:0}
.blackboxes:nth-child(5n+6) {margin-right:0}
.blackboxes:nth-child(3n+6) {margin-right:5px}
```

You may need to make the 6 into a 7 to get things right.

Note that the final styling is meant to over-ride the first effectively isolating the first grouping of six black boxes.

Comment: You are assuming that there are a fixed number of elements on each row.